# How to get Array of Array in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to get `startTime` and `endTime` of an Object inside of an Array?

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let col of timetable" >
        <ion-row  *ngFor="let item in col">
                   {{item.StartTime}}-{{item.EndTime}}<br>{{item.SubjectName}}
       </ion-row>
</ion-col>
```

I want to display in the HTML each data in one column and different row for every array of objects. I have done the HTML part, but its not showing me the data and also I have achieved this through TypeScript nested `for` loop then it and it printed different objects:

```
for (let temp of temptab) {
     for (let tmp of temp) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp));
     }
}
```

Output :

```
{
"startTime" : 08:30:00,
"endTime" : 08:55:00,
"subjectName" : English
}
```

My JSON data :

```
{
  "response": "OK",
  "res": true,
  "timetable": [
    [
      {
        "startTime": "08:30:00",
        "endTime": "08:55:00",
        "subjectName": "English"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "09:55:00",
        "subjectName": "English"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10:00:00",
        "endTime": "10:55:00",
        "subjectName": "Spanish/French"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "11:00:00",
        "endTime": "11:55:00",
        "subjectName": "ICT"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "12:45:00",
        "subjectName": "Lunch break"
      }
    ]
]
```

Comment: what do you mean. I didnt get what you want as result?

Comment: How to get startTime and Endtime in ionic2?

Comment: This is an object in an Array in an Array `timetable[0][0].startTime`, a working example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0afh47f/2/)

Comment: See My edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some errors in your code, most of then are syntax errors.

1 - Your second `*ngFor` is wrong, it's not `let item in col` it must be `let item of col` or it'll throw an error saying the property doesn't know `*ngForIn` because it's an `*ngForOf`.

2 - The properties name are wrong, in your JSON they start with lowercase letters (`startTime`) and in your template you're accessing them with uppercase (`{{item.StartTime}}`), so it can't access since it doesn't exists.

3 - Your grid is wrong, the `row` must come first and then the `col`, so it must be:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Also you need to add the column attributes so it can have the desired size, check the [grid docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) to learn how to do this.

4 - This is not an error since i can't see your full code, so i'm assuming you've passed the `timetable` of your JSON response to a separated property/variable. But if not you must change your first `*ngFor` to reflect it so it can be something like `*ngFor="let col of myVariable.timetable"`.

Hope this helps.